# How to choose encoding when export a CSV on google spreadsheet without using Google Apps Script or Google APIs?

Tags: google-sheets

My goal is to export a CSV from google sheets using encoding UTF-16.

Google sheets is by default exporting CSV in UTF-8 and uses commas to separate values.

I would like to export the CSV in UTF-16 (more precisely UTF-16-LE).

How can I do that directly from google without having to convert the exported file into another encoding? (using a text editor or something else)

Bonus: how to export with a custom the separator? (I would like to use TAB instead of commas)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are comfortable doing this in [Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11338569/13045193) and [Utilities.parseCsv](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String,Char)).

Once you have the data in a 2D array, you can get it in a tab-delimited format with this pattern:

`const tabSeparatedValues = my2dArray.map(row => row.join('\t')).join('\n');`